# Screen Saver (JkDefrag) functionality when monitor powers down

Tags: screensaver, defragment

This may sound like a silly question, but I can't logically decide on the answer.

I am using the JkDefrag in screensaver mode to regularly defrag my hard drive during downtime. If I have my power options set to Power Off monitor after a certain time, will this effectively stop the defrag?

I am interested for both a desktop PC running XP, and a laptop running Vista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powering off the monitor via your O/S's power settings should not affect its determination of whether your machine is idle, and thus in "screen-saver mode".  You'll be able to do both.

Comment: +!: It's been a while since I checked into this, but from previous experience I've found that Windows' screen savers keep running even after the monitor has been put to sleep (as long as the rest of the system is still awake). Reason #2 screen savers are pointless. ;)